# Sum / Mean of the rows between the flags toggle in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

---

```
id  power   flag
0   20      0
1   25      0
2   26      1
3   30      1
4   18      0
5   30      0
6   19      0
7   21      1
8   23      0
```

I am trying to get the mean /sum of rows of **power** column 
the output should look like this

```
0   45 (20 +25)
1   56 (26 + 30)
2   67 (18 +30 +19)
3   21 (21)
4   23 (23)
```

Also what if the flags are not binary?

Can someone help me with these? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, use the cumulative sum of boolean values from `diff.ne(0)` as grouper, and just `sum`

```
df.groupby(df.flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).power.sum()
```

---

```
flag
1    45
2    56
3    67
4    21
5    23
Name: power, dtype: int64
```

Comment: And you can replace `.power.sum()` with `.agg({'power': ['sum', 'mean']})` to get both sum and mean in one fell swoop.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the flags are not binary, 0,1,2,3 values are present for the flag.

Comment: Then you should update with an example closer to your situation ! The code wouldn't change much probably. Once you edit, I can help yuou ;)