# Count the number of events in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

In continuation to my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602680/how-to-get-the-toggle-flag-value-and-sum-of-rows-between-the-flag-toggle/57602744#57602744) I need some more help.

The dataframe is like

```
time eve_id  sub_id   flag
0      5      2        0
1      5      2        0
2      5      2        1
3      5      2        1
4      5      2        0
5      4      25       0
6      4     30        0
7      5      2        1
```

I need to count the eve_id in the time flag goes 0 to 1, 
and count the eve_id for the time flag is 1 to 1

the output will look like this

```
time   flag  count
0       0      2
2       1      2
4       0      3
```

Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 3):

First we make a grouper indicator which checks if the `difference` between two rows is `not equal` to 0, which indicates a difference.

Then we groupby on this indicator and use `agg`. Since `pandas 0.25.0` we have [`named aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling):

```
s = df['flag'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

grpd = df.groupby(s).agg(time=('time', 'first'),
                         flag=('flag', 'first'),
                         count=('flag', 'size')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   time  flag  count
0     0     0      2
1     2     1      2
2     4     0      3
3     7     1      1
```

---

If `time` is your index, use:

```
grpd = df.assign(time=df.index).groupby(s).agg(time=('time', 'first'),
                                               flag=('flag', 'first'),
                                               count=('flag', 'size')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

*notice: the row extra is because there's a difference between the last row and the row before as well*

Answer (score 1):

Change aggregate function `sum` to [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby([df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum(), 'flag'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   flag  count
0     0      2
1     1      2
2     0      3
3     1      1
```